# Are (USB-)FDDs supported by Win 10?

Tags: drivers, windows-10-preview, floppy

Is it possible to use a (USB-)Floppy Disk Drive (3.5") with Windows 10? I have read in a magazine (I think it was c't 14/15, but I'm not sure) that Win 10 would no longer support FDDs (maybe meant: natively).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/windows-10-specifications?OCID=win10_null_vanity_win10specs) says:

> Wenn Sie eine USB-Floppy-Drive betreiben möchten, müssen Sie zuerst den aktuellen Treiber über Windows Update oder die Herstellerseite herunterladen.
>
> (Google translation: *If you want to use a USB floppy drive, you must download the latest drivers from Windows Update or the manufacturer's website first.*)

Comment: The translation isn't all that accurate.  The actual English wordage is "If you have a USB floppy drive, you will need to download the latest driver from Windows Update or from the manufacturer's website." and not "If you want to use a USB floppy drive, you must download the latest drivers from Windows Update or the manufacturer's website first." minor difference but different all the same.

Answer (score 8):

Not true, here is one mounted in my W10 build 10162

[image]

Comment: I did not use Windows update to get it, it was already installed.

Answer (score 2):

#### Drivers for floppy drives are no longer part of the base system and must be downloaded from Windows Update or from the manufacturer's website.

- The [Windows 10 system requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications) state:

> #### Feature deprecation
>
> - If you have a floppy drive, you will need to download the latest driver from Windows Update or from the manufacturer’s website.

- Note that Windows should do this for you automatically when you plug in the drive for the first time, as long as you are online. If you're not online, the drive won't work until you connect to the Internet and get the driver.